Why does nullary constructors in GHC Haskell take two machine words?
I experimented with the closureSize# primitive in GHC. Here I define the helper function I use (x is forced using a bang pattern, so what I am measuring should be the data constructor closures themselves rather than the thunks).
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}
import GHC.Exts
import Text.Printf
size :: Show a => a -> IO ()
size !x = printf "sizeof %s = %d\n" (showsPrec 11 x "") (I# (closureSize# x))

Now in GHCi, below are the weird results:
GHCi> size ()
sizeof () = 2
GHCi> size (MkSolo 1)
sizeof (MkSolo 1) = 2
GHCi> size (1, 2)
sizeof (1,2) = 3
GHCi> size (1, 2, 3)
sizeof (1,2,3) = 4
GHCi> size Nothing
sizeof Nothing = 2
GHCi> size (Just 42)
sizeof (Just 42) = 2
GHCi> size []
sizeof [] = 2
GHCi> size [1, 2, 3]
sizeof [1,2,3] = 3

Everything but the nullary constructors makes sense to me. I thought they should only take one single word for the STG info header, but instead they take two words. Is this due to some restrictions in GHC RTS that every closure must have at least one word of payload?

I have no idea, but maybe two words are always allocated so that the closure can be replaced with something else? It looks like indirections have 1 word payload. Is that the reason? Or is it for GC purposes?

It has to do with garbage collection.  See the comment Mark bits in mark-compact collector for details.
For the mark-sweep garbage collection, the GC uses two bits per closure.  Instead of allocating these on a per-object basis, the bitmap is based on heap words, with one bit allocated per heap word.  This makes a one-word heap object too small (because it'll only have one associated bit), so all heap objects have a minimum size of 2 words (or, equivalently, a MIN_PAYLOAD size of 1).

Surprisingly, nullary constructors use the same representation as unary constructors. You can confirm this using the ghc-heap library which is part of GHC.
$ ghci
> :set -package ghc-heap
package flags have changed, resetting and loading new packages...
> import GHC.Exts.Heap
> getClosureData Nothing
ConstrClosure {info = StgInfoTable {entry = Nothing, ptrs = 0, nptrs = 1, tipe = CONSTR_0_1, srtlen = 0, code = Nothing}, ptrArgs = [], dataArgs = [140686603053880], pkg = "base", modl = "GHC.Maybe", name = "Nothing"}

The closure type (tipe field) is CONSTR_0_1: a CONSTRuctor with 0 pointer fields and 1 non-pointer fields. Note that there is no CONSTR_0_0 closure type (see ClosureType). I don't know why that is. I encourage you to ask this question on the Haskell mailing list or Discourse to get a more expert answer!
This old GHC wiki page on Heap Objects explains what those closure types correspond to.
